# First order of logic - x is a power of 2

Tags: first-order-logic

I don't think something like (we can assume that the formula is over $\mathbb{N}$):

$\exists y. 2^y=x$

is allowed (it may be - I am just not sure).

I don't see a way to do it recursively without reaching an infinite formula.

Can anyone help please?

Edit: Using power in the formula is not allowed, and according to my professor this should be done using division and the unique prime factorization of a number.

Comment: does that mean 'for every $y$ there is an $x$ such that $x = 2^y$' ?

Comment: @Spectre No? It means that there exists $y$ so that $2^y=x$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is exponentiation defined in Peano arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312891/how-is-exponentiation-defined-in-peano-arithmetic)

Comment: @lemontree Thank you. The solution proposed in the second answer seems too complicated for the level we were taught at. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: If there were a known simpler way, you can be assured Hagen and Andrés (whose answer expands on and explains Hagen's) would have given it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I asked the professor and he said that we should use division, and the unique prime factorization of a number.

Comment: Ummm What *exactly* is the questioh you are trying to answer?? You have never made that clear, and it now appears that no one who has responded so far has been correct in our guesses.